# Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, html

I recently created a code that adjusts a divisions height when you press different arrow keys. 
Unfortunately, it is not actually doing that.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here - it only tells me Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected end of input

The code is as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Grow your own div</title>
    <script>
        var high = box.style.offsetHeight;
        var wide = box.style.offsetWidth;
        window.onkeydown = function(){
            if (event.keyCode === 37){
                if (box.style.offsetWidth > 0) {
                    wide = wide--;
                    box.style.offsetWidth = wide;
                }
                else {
                    box.style.offsetWidth = 1;
                }
            }
            else if (event.keyCode === 38) {
                high = high++;
                box.style.offsetHeight = high;
            }
            else if (event.keyCode === 39) {
                wide = wide++;
                box.style.offsetWidth = wide;
            }
            else if (event.keyCode === 40) {
                if (box.style.offsetHeight > 0) {
                    high = high--;
                    box.style.offsetHeight = high;
                }
                else {
                    box.style.offsetHeight = 1;
                }

            }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div style="height:100px; width:100px; background-color:orange; position:relative" id="box">   
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am not proficient in either JavaScript nor HTML,please refer to my profile if you would like to know more.

Comment: Your braces are not balanced, which you would be able to see easily if you formatted your code.

Comment: Your HTML is also invalid--you are closing a `div` tag with `<div>` instead of `</div>`.

Comment: There is some problems. for example it should be `wide++` instead of `wide = wide++;`. check this jsfiddle.
[http://jsfiddle.net/zfoqe8pz/](http://jsfiddle.net/zfoqe8pz/)

Comment: If you use String.fromCharCode, you can turn the keyCode that you get from window.onkeydown into the letter without having to memorize all the keyCodes.

Answer (score 0):

I find two problems with your code here.  I have formatted it below to allow it to be read more easily.  Note that the function opened at window.onkeydown() is not closed.  You need an additional close curly brace before the end script tag.  The other problem is that you have two div tags in the body where you meant to have a div and a /div.

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>Grow your own div</title>
     <script>
          var high = box.style.offsetHeight;
          var wide = box.style.offsetWidth;
          window.onkeydown = function(){
               if (event.keyCode === 37){
                    if (box.style.offsetWidth > 0){
                         wide = wide--;
                         box.style.offsetWidth = wide;
                    }
                    else {
                         box.style.offsetWidth = 1;
                    }
               }
               else if (event.keyCode === 38){
                    high = high++;
                    box.style.offsetHeight = high;
               }
               else if (event.keyCode === 39){
                    wide = wide++;
                    box.style.offsetWidth = wide;
               }
               else if (event.keyCode === 40){
                    if (box.style.offsetHeight > 0){
                         high = high--;
                         box.style.offsetHeight = high;
                    }
                    else {
                         box.style.offsetHeight = 1;
                    }
               }
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div style="height:100px; width:100px; background-color:orange; position:relative" id="box">
     <div>
  </body>
</html>
```